# ApexCharts - Custom bar colour

Tags: apexcharts

Is it possible to customise the colour of each bar in a column chart ?

This is the kind of data I'm having using React:

```
const [data, setData] = useState([{
    data: [{
        x: 'Apple',
        y: 54,
        color: '#CCCCCC'
    }, {
        x: 'Orange',
        y: 66,
        color: '#FF0000'
    }]
}]);
```

But the colours here is are not applied to the chart.

I've tried with the 'distributed' option set to true as well.

```
plotOptions: {
        bar: {
            distributed: true,
        },
    },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve this, you're very close to both of them.

**1. Pass the color with the data**

Very similar to what you've tried, but use `fillColor` as the key instead.

```
data: [{
        x: 'Apple',
        y: 54,
        fillColor: '#CCCCCC'
    }, {
        x: 'Orange',
        y: 66,
        fillColor: '#FF0000'
    }]
```

**2. `distributed` option**

For this to work, it needs to be nested inside the `options` object:

```
options: {
  plotOptions: {
    bar: {
      distributed: true
    }
  }
},
```

If this doesn't work, it's worth making sure that there aren't any invalid attributes (e.g. `color`) somewhere that might be causing issues.

As I'm sure you've already discovered, there are some examples of various ways to use colors in a column chart in the [ApexCharts docs](https://apexcharts.com/docs/chart-types/column-chart/).